# How to acquire multiple streams with different device constraints in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm trying to acquire different MediaStreams while specifying a different `deviceId` in each case.

For example: I have 3 microphones (`audioinputs`) available and would like to acquire an audio stream for each of them.

1. streamC1: with `deviceId` 4hYbpq3YGKqNN6RbbLz5HrLfolsmjFDMl8sY
2. streamC2: with `deviceId` MZ0gdxcs1Q0NW0sobM8ri3kfDhmOs1K74e2p
3. streamC3: with `deviceId` iUWqFDfruPGcT6nl9gUxeN6dCM8VfFH5ZmR8

   ```
   const c1 = { audio: { deviceId: { exact: audioInputs[0].deviceId } } };
   const c2 = { audio: { deviceId: { exact: audioInputs[1].deviceId } } };
   const c3 = { audio: { deviceId: { exact: audioInputs[2].deviceId } } };

   getMedia(c1)
    .then(() => getMedia(c2))
    .then(() => getMedia(c3));
   ```

[Here is a complete JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z61n3uuu/9/).

This works fine in Chrome (Version 55.0.2883.87) and I get 3 different streams (C1, C2, C3) with all audioTracks having the expected labels.

[image: chrome output]

But fails with the second and third call to `getUserMedia` (C2, C3) in Firefox (50.0.2) with the following error:

[image: firefox output]

[According to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) for `NotReadableErrors`:

> Although the user granted permission to use the matching devices, a hardware error occurred at the operating system, browser, or Web page level which prevented access to the device.

(I can however acquire multiple streams with the same constraints without running into that problem.)

Is Firefox behaving as expected here? Since the docs mention a **"hardware error"**?
Is there a different way to acquire multiple streams (with different device constraints)? Or do I have to stop the streams, releasing the devices and then acquiring the new stream?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently (Nightly is now 53) Firefox doesn't support multiple active audio input sources.

It's something we're thinking about, but it requires a couple of fairly major changes to our MediaStream plumbing. It's all related to drift - inputs (and outputs) running off different clocks.

We're considering taking an intermediate step towards this by interpreting a request for a new device as an intention to switch devices. That allows us to keep the first open while the prompt for the second is visible and then switch seamlessly. This is relatively low-hanging fruit for the issue in [bug 1299324](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1299324).

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the quick response. So multiple active **video input sources** should work without issue? (I did a quick test and it seems to work). And for the moment I'd have to stop the tracks in order to free the associated device?

Comment: Correct and correct. And beware that devices can usually not be acquired if they're already acquired by a different process.